# Getting an array variable whose size is defined with a variable to take an assignment?

Tags: c++, arrays

the objective of the code below is to take user entered variables (a and c), multiply them (a*c), find the factors of this number and then find which of these factors add up to another user entered variable (in this case, b). For some reason, it is not compiling correctly and I cannot understand why. When I try to use the command `cout << sum1 << endl << sum2 << endl;`it displays wild, unpredictable numbers. Can anyone tell me if there is something wrong with my code? This is also a void funtion that returns the values sum1 and sum2 (created in the function) to main. The variables a, b, c, and f[] are all defined in main. Here is the function declaration:

```
void findFactors(int, int, int, int[], int&, int&);
```

And the function itself:

```
void findFactors(int a, int b, int c, int f[], int& sum1, int& sum2)
{   
    int j=0;
    int mult=a*c;
    int i, z=j, temp;

    for(i=1; i<=mult; i++)
    {
        if(mult%i==0)
        {
           f[j]=i;
           j++;
        }   
    }

    for(j=0; j>=0; j--)
    {
        temp=mult/f[j];
        if(temp+f[z]==b || temp-f[z]==b || f[z]-temp==b)
        {
           sum1 = f[z];
           sum2 = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Please also share the code using the function

Comment: why `for(j=0; j>=0; j--)` loop, doesn't it just execute once since `j` is `-1` after the first loop?

Comment: How big is the `f` array that's passed to the function?

Comment: Given the above code, `f[0] = 1` since any number `%1 == 0`, then since your `j` loop executes only once, `temp` will equal `mult / 1` and then only if `b == temp + 1 or temp - 1, or 1 - temp` will your `sum1` and `sum2` values be set

Answer (score 1):

```
void findFactors(int a, int b, int c, int f[], int& sum1, int& sum2)
{   
   int j=0;
   int mult=a*c;
   int i, z=j, temp; // here z == 0

   for(i = 1; i <= mult; i++)
   {
      if(mult % i == 0)
      {
         f[j] = i;   // Any # % 1 == 0, so f[0] = 1
         j++;        // note: z is still == 0 here
      }   
   }

   for(j = 0; j >= 0; j--)   // This loop executes only once
   {
      temp = mult / f[j]; // f[0] == 1, so temp == mult here
      // since z==0 here, f[0] == 1
      // so only if: b == (temp + 1) || (temp - 1) || (1 - temp) 
      if(temp + f[z] == b || temp - f[z] == b || f[z] - temp == b)
      {
         sum1 = f[z];   // z is still 0, so f[0] is 1, sum1 == 1
         sum2 = temp;   // temp == mult here, so sum2 == mult
      }
   }
}
```

Not sure if this function is working how you expect it to, but unless those conditions for the variable `b` are met, then `sum1` and `sum2` are never getting set, and if they ARE, `sum1` should be being set to `1`, and `sum2` should be `temp` or `mult`